# Why is my Button event is not occuring?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button

I am having an issue with my button event not occuring

Basically I have cart items that are listed in the listbox. When the delete button is clicked then the item is deleted from the list box.

I tried debugging, but it seems to not even call the method for when the button is clicked.

In my ticketscreen.xaml file I specify my button in the template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TicketTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50">
...
        <Button Name="Remove" Width="35" Height="35"
                FontFamily="Resources/#charlemagnestd-regular.otf" FontSize="24"
                Click="removeCartItem" Grid.Column="5"
                MouseMove="Remove_MouseMove">X</Button>
...
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My List box is the following:

```
<ListBox Name="TicketItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TicketTemplate}"
         Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Background="Transparent"
         BorderBrush="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False">
</ListBox>
```

My method removeCartItem is in the ticketscreen.xaml.cs:

```
private void removeCartItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TestingCartRemove");
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?
Thx in adv! :)

Edit:
There seems to be something infront of it... maybe the listbox? How do I make it so that I am not clicking the ListBox, but I can click on things within the Stackpanel, which are contents of the list box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsHitTestVisible="False" for the ListBox is disabling the click event for the Button. It makes all content within the ListBox invisible to hit-test as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure is not firing? Maybe you haven't seen the output in Visual Studio Output Window. Try to call a `MessageBox.Show("Test");` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have a listbox control, which leads me to believe that this is not a console application. Therefore, `Console.WriteLine()` will not show you anything. Try `MessageBox.Show()` instead.

Comment: Good point but the OP states "I tried debugging," so we have to assume he set a break point in `removeCartItem` and it doesn't get hit.

Comment: Well, I figured I'd start with answering "Am I missing something obvious"